# Prove that: $\sum \dfrac{a^2-bc}{2a^2+b^2+c^2} \ge 0$ ; $a,b,c>0$

Tags: inequality

$->\text{Using}$ $Cauchy$:

$$=> - \sum \dfrac{bc}{2a^2+b^2+c^2} \ge -(\dfrac{b^2+c^2}{4a^2+2b^2+2c^2}+\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{4c^2+2a^2+2b^2}+\dfrac{a^2+c^2}{4b^2+2a^2+2c^2}) = \sum -[\dfrac{a^2}{2}.(\dfrac{1}{2b^2+a^2+c^2}+\dfrac{1}{2c^2+a^2+b^2}]$$

$->\text{Using:}$ $\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y} \ge \dfrac{4}{x+y}$

$$=>VT \ge \sum -[\dfrac{a^2}{8}.(\dfrac{1}{b^2+a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2+c^2} +\dfrac{1}{c^2+a^2}+\dfrac{1}{c^2+b^2}] \ge \sum -[\dfrac{a^2}{32}.(\dfrac{1}{b^2}+\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}+\dfrac{1}{c^2}+\dfrac{1}{c^2}+\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{c^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}) = \sum -[\dfrac{a^2}{32}.(\dfrac{2}{a^2}+\dfrac{3}{b^2}+\dfrac{3}{c^2})]$$

$\text{Then,we have:}$

$$=>\sum \dfrac{a^2-bc}{2a^2+b^2+c^2} \ge \sum [\dfrac{a^2}{2a^2+b^2+c^2} -\dfrac{a^2}{32}.(\dfrac{2}{a^2}+\dfrac{3}{b^2}+\dfrac{3}{c^2})] = \sum [\dfrac{1}{2+\dfrac{b^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{c^2}{a^2}} - \dfrac{1}{32}.(2+\dfrac{3a^2}{b^2}+\dfrac{3a^2}{c^2})] (''*'')$$

$\text{Let}$: \begin{array}{l}x=\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}\\y=\dfrac{b^2}{c^2} \\ z = \dfrac{c^2}{a^2} \\ x,y,z >0\end{array}

$=>$ $(''*'')$ $\text{become:}$ $\sum [\dfrac{1}{2+\dfrac{1}{x}+z} - \dfrac{1}{32}.(2+3x+\dfrac{3}{z})] $

$\text{Using}$ $Cauchy–Schwarz$:

$$=>VT \ge  \dfrac{9}{x+y+z+\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y}+\dfrac{1}{z}+6} - \dfrac{3}{32}.(2+x+y+z+\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y}+\dfrac{1}{z})$$

$\text{Let}$: $x+y+z+\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y}+\dfrac{1}{z}= t$ $(t \ge 6)$

$$=> VT \ge \dfrac{9}{t+6}-\dfrac{3}{32}.(2+t)= \dfrac{9}{t+6}-\dfrac{3}{32}.t-\dfrac{3}{16}=3.(\dfrac{3}{t+6}-\dfrac{1}{32}.t-\dfrac{2}{32})= 3.(\dfrac{-t^2-8t+84}{32.(t+6)} )= 3.\dfrac{-(t-6)(t+14)}{32.(t+6)} ??\ge 0$$
->In there, I have mistake with that. Can you help me fix it? or come up with another solution?

$Where : t=6 =>x=y=z => a=b=c$

Comment: What makes you say that you "have a mistake"? It seems that your inequality was loosened too much to prove the original, but I don't consider that as a "mistake". Can you elaborate?

Comment: $Sum_{cyc}...{}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: The first line is the crux. With that, show that $ \sum \frac{ 2a^2 } { 2a^2 + b^2 + c^2 } \geq \sum \frac{ b^2 + c^2 } { 2a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$ which is a "standard" inequality.

Comment: Yes, $\sum_{cyc}$ @markvs

Comment: Also https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1410638p7923606 on AoPS.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Using $b^2+c^2\geq 2bc$ we get $$ \dfrac{a^2-bc}{2a^2+b^2+c^2} \geq   {1\over 2}\cdot \dfrac{2a^2-b^2-c^2}{2a^2+2b^2+2c^2} $$

Comment: What is wrong with this hint?